# Draw Sphere - order of vertices

Tags: geometry, opengl-es-2.0

I would like draw sphere in pure OpenGL ES 2.0 without any engines. I write next code:

```
 int GenerateSphere (int Slices, float radius, GLfloat **vertices, GLfloat **colors) {
 srand(time(NULL));
 int i=0, j = 0;
 int Parallels = Slices ;
 float tempColor = 0.0f;    
 int VerticesCount = ( Parallels + 1 ) * ( Slices + 1 );
 float angleStep = (2.0f * M_PI) / ((float) Slices);

 // Allocate memory for buffers
 if ( vertices != NULL ) {
    *vertices = malloc ( sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * VerticesCount );
 }
 if ( colors != NULL) {
    *colors = malloc( sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * VerticesCount);
 }

 for ( i = 0; i < Parallels+1; i++ ) {
     for ( j = 0; j < Slices+1 ; j++ ) {

         int vertex = ( i * (Slices + 1) + j ) * 3;

         (*vertices)[vertex + 0] = radius * sinf ( angleStep * (float)i ) *
                    sinf ( angleStep * (float)j );
         (*vertices)[vertex + 1] = radius * cosf ( angleStep * (float)i );
         (*vertices)[vertex + 2] = radius * sinf ( angleStep * (float)i ) *
                        cosf ( angleStep * (float)j );
         if ( colors ) {
                int colorIndex = ( i * (Slices + 1) + j ) * 4;
                tempColor = (float)(rand()%100)/100.0f;

                (*colors)[colorIndex + 0] =  0.0f;
                (*colors)[colorIndex + 1] =  0.0f;
                (*colors)[colorIndex + 2] =  0.0f;
                (*colors)[colorIndex + (rand()%4)] = tempColor;
                (*colors)[colorIndex + 3] =  1.0f;
            }
        }
    }
    return VerticesCount;
}
```

I'm drawing it with using next code:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, userData->numVertices);
```

Where userData->numVertices - VerticesCount from function GenerateSphere.
But on screen draws series triangles, these aren't sphere approximation!
I think, I need to numerate vertices and use OpenGL ES 2.0 function glDrawElements() (with array, contained number vertices). But series of triangles drawn on the screen is not a sphere approximation. 
How can I draw sphere approximation? How specify order vertices (indices in OpenGL ES 2.0 terms)?

Comment: I generally use the function esGenSphere from the GLES2 programming guide. The one from the book (and svn) generates wrong texcoord y though; this is fixed in https://github.com/laanwj/etna_viv/blob/master/native/lib/esShapes.c . It generates vertices as well as indices.

Answer (score 11):

Before you start with anything in OpenGL ES, here is some advice:

> Avoid bloating CPU/GPU performance

Removing intense cycles of calculations by rendering the shapes offline using another program will surely help. These programs will provide additional details about the shapes/meshes apart from exporting the resultant collection of points [x,y,z] comprising the shapes etc.

I went through all this pain way back, because I kept trying to search for algorithms to render spheres etc and then trying to optimize them. I just wanted to save your time in the future. Just use Blender and then your favorite programming language to parse the obj files that are exported from Blender, I use Perl. Here are the steps to render sphere: (use glDrawElements because the obj file contains the array of indices)

```
1) Download and install Blender.
```

[image: image-1]

```
2) From the menu, add sphere and then reduce the number of rings and segments.
```

[image: image-2]

```
3) Select the entire shape and triangulate it.
```

[image: image-3]

```
4) Export an obj file and parse it for the meshes.
```

[image: image-4]

You should be able to grasp the logic to render sphere from this file: http://pastebin.com/4esQdVPP. It is for Android, but the concepts are same.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It's good advice! But.. how get texture coordinates in blender?
I can't find (i didn't use blender in the past)
Thank you a lot!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3M21GqAgHM this is my favourite video on blender adding textures

Comment: I agree with the gist of your post. However, the GenerateSphere call has only to be called once at initialization to build the vertex/index buffer. This still creates some overhead at init, but makes no difference in eventual rendering performance.

Comment: I agree; but... while developing a typical ES 2.0/3.0 application it is very unlikely that you will only render a sphere ;-) Scenes end up being a lot more complex than that - which is why the opening line was - @"Before you start with anything in OpenGL ES, here is some advice:" :)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with spheres and other geometric shapes. I worked at it a while and created an Objective-C class to create coordinates, normals, and texture coordinates both using indexed and non-indexed mechanisms, the class is here:

http://www.whynotsometime.com/Why_Not_Sometime/Code_Snippets.html

What is interesting to see the resulting triangles representing the geometry is to reduce the resolution (set the resolution property before generating the coordinates). Also, you can use GL_LINE_STRIP instead of GL_TRIANGLES to see a bit more.

I agree with the comment from wimp that since calculating the coordinates generally happens once, not many CPU cycles are used.  Also, sometimes one does want to draw only a ball or world or...